# Rails paperclip amazon aws s3 gem, how to change image url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

In my model I have:

```
  has_attached_file :image,
          :storage => :s3,
          :styles => { :original => ["300x250>", :png], :small => ["165x138>", :png], :mini => ["120x120>", :png] },
          :path => 'images/vind/:style/:id/:basename.:extension',
          :url => 'images/vind/:style/:id/:basename.png',
          :bucket => 'konkurrencerher',
          :s3_credentials => {
          :access_key_id => 'x',
          :secret_access_key => 'x'
  }
```

The problem is just that there is added the amazon s3 hostname to the url in view.

I have a solution to this, but is a bit ugly:

```
<%= image_tag(kon.photo.image.url(:small).gsub("http://s3.amazonaws.com/konkurrencerher", ""), :class => 'koni') %>
```

But, how is it possible to define the image url in the model, without the Amazon S3 hostname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution created a file in the initializers map with this:

```
Paperclip.interpolates(:s3_path_url) { |attachment, style|
  "#{(attachment.path).gsub("images/", "")}"
}
```

And then the url should be:

```
:url => ':s3_path_url'
```

This is a much better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `Paperclip::Storage::S3`, especially on the `:s3_host_alias`.

You can try configuring your `has_attached_file` with the following additional options

```
 :url => ':s3_alias_url',
 :s3_host_alias => "example.domain.net"
```

Hope this helps.